# How to collect messages after a question? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to collect an answer after a user send it after the bot sends it after the user sends the command,
I know it's weird but let me give you an example: If a user sends '!shop add' the bot will response and say 'what is your item name?' and then I want to get the answer from the user.

```js
if(msg.content === '!shop add'){


msg.channel.send('What is your item name?')
//User: @admins

//Or

//User: Car

msg.channel.send('And how much does it cost?')

//User: 10

msg.channel.send('Item Succesfully Added')

}
```

Comment: Use [TextChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [`.awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) method in a channel property of the message. Use it, along with some filters (like userID of message author), to create a collection of messages.

```
   if(msg.content === '!shop add'){
   const filter = m => m.author.id == msg.author.id;
   msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
     .then(collection => {
   let replyMessage = collection.first(); //the message you wanted to obtain
        //if (replyMessage.content == 'yes') ...
   })
   .catch();
```

Comment: Thanks you solved the problem! I love programmers that solve it fast like you!!!

Comment: But, can I add an await inside an await!

Comment: @Hassan_BH since this is a method that returns a promise, yes you can (although I haven't tested it, so feel free to try it out)

Comment: I tested it and it actually worked Thanks alot!!!!!!

Comment: glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a MessageCollector, is better than awaitMessages function. Here the link to the
[documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector)

Try to watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzKBwdhyvzM) at the minute 8:15.

Sorry for bad english!